# Xpath syntax to grab listed elements based on ID above containing word

Tags: xpath

I want to grab li element text and links from a list. The challenge is, the span  sometimes has different class names BUT always has the word 'notable' featured in them, example:

```
<span class="mw-headline" id="Notable_alumni">Notable alumni</span>
```

OR

```
<span class="mw-headline" id="Notable_former_pupils">Notable former pupils</span>
```

So I need to use "contains" somehow, so I am along these lines:

```
//li[contains(span/@id,'Notable')]/span/@id/following-sibling::text()
```

But can't get this right.

Another issue is these blocks of text and headers are not in the same containing div either. Added an image to simplify and you can see the code.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if the example provided was the actual xHTML (not a screenshot), and if you provided an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the span with the `@id` is always under the `h2` (you could make more generic by using `*` instead of `h2` if that doesn't hold true). If you anchor to that containing element, then look for the first `ul` that is a following-sibling, you can select the `text()` from all of it's `li` elements:

```
//h2[span[contains(@id,'Movie Title')]]/following-sibling::ul[1]/li//text()
```

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong example and the class 'Movie title', as per the code, this is nothing to do with this. The span id contains the word 'notable'. I still cannot get this to work,

Comment: What is the desired output? It is not clear which `text()` you are trying to select.

Comment: "Max Beesley" and "Jiafeng Chen" and any other li class text that appears beneath them (we can only see 2 on this screengrab)